# How to access a Windows Server 2008 network share from Windows Vista Home Edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share

Is there any way to allow access a network share on Windows Server 2008 to a specific Vista Home machine/user?

I have two Vista Home machines on my network (ugh) and I need a user from one of them to be able to access a network share on my new server 2008 DC. How ever I don't want to just allow "everyone" access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Server 2008 and a Vista. I enabled file service under server role on Server 2008, and have matching username and password on both machine. To access the file share on Server 2008 from Vista, I simply type `\\myserver\myshare` in explorer! Very easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well. I created shares on server 2008, but have been unable to access them on Windows Vista or Win 7.
The shortcut I got to this was to create a VPN link to the server from either the LAN or field offices, and I'm able to open the shares.
If anyone gets a better solution, do inform me.